# NAs in converting a characteric variable to intteger

Tags: r, type-conversion, numeric

Do you need to drop the NAs if converting a character to an integer variable? For example, this is the message I receive. The summary indicates that it is now a string but there are NAs appearing in the summary statistics. Should these values be dropped?

```
     data$var1<-as.numeric(data$var1)
 Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion 
     summary(data$var1)
Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max.     NA's 
0.05   150.21   405.79  1005.55  1130.61 27934.00       34
```

Comment: It depends. Do you "think" that everything is a valid number? If so, this should be an error for you. If you know that at least one of your strings is not a real number, then this error might be fine, but ... you may still need to verify which values are `NA` to see if you are misunderstanding what you have. For instance, `as.integer(c("2. 3","1..9"))` produces two NAs, no numbers, and the issue is due to string formatting (and not too difficult to fix, in this case).

Comment: Hello krisili, it depends on your task, but usually it is not necessary and sometimes desirable to preserve them, because they give you valuable information: that the data in thep position of NA is missing. Some functions like sum, mean, etc have the argument (na.rm=TRUE)  to omit them so you not need to remove them to perform sums.